# Push new objects created from class into array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

I've got a class Student with constructor for name of student.
I want to easily generate an array of all students with names 'Student 1', Student 2', ...

I was thinking two for loops:

```
    function generateNames (studentAmount) {
        for (let i = 0; i < studentAmount; i++) {
            generateNicknames.push('Student' + [i + 1])
        }
        return generateNicknames
    }
    
    let allStudents = [] 
    function generateStudents(arrayOfNames) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayOfNnames.length; j++) {
            allStudents.push(new Student(arrayOfNames[j]))
        }
        return allStudents
    }
```

The first one generates an array with ['Student 1', 'Student 2', ] etc. But the second one only generates '[Student, Student, Student...]

Any suggestions?

Comment: `arrayOfNnames` => `arrayOfNames`. It's a typo.

Comment: You are likely seeing `Student` being displayed in your console. This just stands in for an object of type `Student`. Since we don't know how `Student` class (or constructor) is defined, it is not really possible to say whether or not their names are set correctly; but the difference is that in the first case you have an array of strings, and in the other an array of objects.

Comment: If you simply do `console.log(allStudents)` it will be printed as '[Student, Student, ...]'. If you want to print the names you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(allStudents))`. You should be able to see all the nicknames in the console then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have moved the empty array inside the first function: it is always a good idea to keep all variables you are modifying inside the function if possible. This way you will avoid collisions and unexpected behaviour more easily.

Finally, I have also refactored your second function to make it shorter using `map()` function.

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
function generateNames(studentAmount) {
  const nicknames = []; // the array is now inside the function
  for (let i = 0; i < studentAmount; i++) {
    nicknames.push(`Student${i + 1}`);
  }
  return nicknames;
}

function generateStudents(arrayOfNames) {
  return arrayOfNames.map((name) =>  new Student(name));
}

const names = generateNames(10);
const students = generateStudents(names);
console.log(students) // [Student {name: 'Student1', ...}, ... Student {name: 'Student10', ... }]
```

Comment: Thanks for that!I also realised I was missing a toString() to make it print what I wanted! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work, it can be easily achieved by using array.map.
I can propose easier way for the `generateStudents` function to

```js
function generateStudents(arrayOfNames) {
  return arrayOfNames.map(name => new Student(name))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was also missing a toString() to make it work properly :)